# Android: How to change ListView's scrolling trigger "sensibility"?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

When vertically sliding finger on a ListView, it starts to scroll after a small move.

Is there any way to increase this "gap", so it would be necessary a "larger" move to trigger the ListView's scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing explicit like `setSensitivity` but you might be able to set a flag to detect when the ListView isn't scrolling. So then onScroll if the flag is set to true, (meaning that it has started scrolling from a fixed position), set the flag to false, and in the override of the scroll method only allow it to scroll once the amount is over 10dip for example...

Then when it stops scrolling again, set the flag back to true.

It's just an abstract idea but it sounds like it could work.